# Cant make user's photoURL null on firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Cant make current users photoURL section null in firebase

```
      var user = auth().currentUser

                user.updateProfile({photoURL: null}).then(function() {

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        Alert.alert('Profile Picture Removed')
                    }, 100);                      

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console('UPDATE PROFILE ERROR ' + error)

                })
```

Using this code block as per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile), its running the .then function despite its not doing the update (giving the success alert not the error). Its just stays as it is.

Instead of null, it can be updated to another string without any problem, but i need to null it, nulling is not working. Any thoughts, is it a bug or something ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that checks the call to `updateProfile` for success or failure, as what you have now might be failing - we can't tell.  `updateProfile` returns a promise that indicates what happens. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile

Comment: Ok i added the whole function and why im trying to do that

Comment: Your code still isn't checking the result of the call to `updateProfile`.

Comment: Ok I understand now what you mean, if i put some console.log into .then() i am getting the log. So its working according to firebase. But its not 'nulling' the photoURL.

Comment: How do you know it is not?  What specifically are you observing?  How would someone reproduce the problematic behavior?

Comment: I am logging current user for check with this ; console.log(JSON.stringify(auth().currentUser)).. Also, i am rendering profile photo with that url so it shouldnt be rendering after deleting. But its rendering. Because its still there.

Comment: OK, now use the documentation for the web SDK to get an ID token for the user as shown in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients

Comment: How will getting an ID token help me in this case ? The link which you put at your first comment is already exact thing what i want to do. But its not working on me: updateProfile({photoURL: null})

Comment: Still got this problem, any thoughts ? its still not nulling the value

Comment: Having the same issue, even after logging the user out and in it didn't set the photoURL to `null`. I have no problems setting it to `strings`but `null` seem to not work which is weird because after inspecting the function it allows to receive it.